# Script to find unused indexes over a period of time doesn't work in Oracle 11g

Tags: index, index-tuning, oracle-11g, snapshot

The `statspack_unused_indexes.sql` script described in [this page](http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_unused_indexes.htm) would be *incredibly* useful to me, but it has been coded for an earlier version of Oracle. When I try to run it on 11g, I get the following error:

```
SQL> @statspack_unused_indexes.sql
Enter value for begin_snap: 10000
Enter value for end_snap: 10600
old  48:    sn.snap_id between &begin_snap and &end_snap
new  48:    sn.snap_id between 10000 and 10600
   stats$sql_plan_usage spu
   *
ERROR at line 28:
ORA-00980: synonym translation is no longer valid
```

Is there some easy patch to make that work on 11g? Here's the code (copied from the referenced page):

```
ttitle "Unused Indexes by Time Period"

col owner heading "Index Owner" format a30
col index_name heading "Index Name" format a30

set linesize 95 trimspool on pagesize 80

select * 
from
   (select 
      owner, 
      index_name
   from 
      dba_indexes di
   where
      di.index_type != 'LOB'
   and
      owner not in ('SYS', 'SYSMAN', 'SYSTEM', 'MDSYS', 'WMSYS', 'TSMSYS', 'DBSNMP', 'OUTLN')
minus
select 
   index_owner owner, 
   index_name
from 
   dba_constraints dc
where
   index_owner not in ('SYS', 'SYSMAN', 'SYSTEM', 'MDSYS', 'WMSYS', 'TSMSYS', 'DBSNMP', 'OUTLN')
minus
select
   p.object_owner owner,
   p.object_name  index_name
from
   stats$snapshot       sn,
   stats$sql_plan       p,
   stats$sql_summary    st,
   stats$sql_plan_usage spu
where
   st.sql_id = spu.sql_id 
and 
   spu.plan_hash_value = p.plan_hash_value
and
   st.hash_value = p.plan_hash_value
and
   sn.snap_id = st.snap_id 
and 
   sn.dbid = st.dbid 
and 
   sn.instance_number = st.instance_number
and
   sn.snap_id = spu.snap_id
and 
   sn.dbid = spu.snap_id 
and 
   sn.instance_number = spu.instance_number
and
   sn.snap_id between &begin_snap and &end_snap
and
   p.object_type = 'INDEX'
)
where owner not in ('SYS', 'SYSMAN', 'SYSTEM', 'MDSYS', 'WMSYS', 'TSMSYS', 'DBSNMP', 'OUTLN')
order by 1, 2
/
```

Comment: Is Statspack installed in your database?  It's never installed by default.  Are you licensed to use the AWR?  If so, you could just query the `dba_hist*` tables.